# Authentication issue when adding Firebase to an existing web application

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have an existing web application - https://codiva.io that runs on AWS. Now I need to add some dashboard, provide offline support etc, and I see Firebase to be one of the best option available.

Now I need to setup authorization such that, when a user logs in, they are automatically signed in to both the existing AWS server and also the Firebase, so they can access content from both the places.

Similarly, I would also need to setup (AWSnodejs - Firebase)server-server communication, so that I can continue with some batch processing, server side syncing etc.

The Firebase examples I see only do one of these things, either show browser-Firebase authorization or Firebase - Server authorization, but not both at the same time.

How does login work in this case especially when social network login are added, do they have to login multiple times to the site?

---

Juan Acosta pointed out, one solution using custom authentication, where the user signed in to my server, can generate a token that can be used to authenticate access to firebase. 
Is it possible to do the reverse? Authentication actually done by firebase, and pass some kind of token that I could use to authenticate in my server. Advantage, even if my server is down, only part of the functionality will be unavailable for the user once the files are also hosted in the server.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue and I recently found this documentation:

For version 3:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#create_a_custom_token

For version 2:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

That states:

> If you have existing server-side authentication or single sign-on, you can also easily integrate it with Firebase. Download one of our helper libraries to generate authentication tokens on your own servers.

Comment: Thanks Juan Acosta. This seem to work. 
Is it possible to do the reverse? Like authenticate with firebase and use some kind of token to authenticate with my server running in aws. The advantage is, I can move my hosting and everything to firebase itself and leave only compilation and running the programs in my server.

I am updating the question with this too.